# An alternative to a static variable in a member function

Tags: c++, templates, static

I have been relying on the misconception that static variables defined in member functions were limited to the specific class instance.

To illustrate my misconception:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Simple {
    template<typename T>
    T & Test(const T & Value) {
        static T Storage = Value;
        return Storage;
    }
};

int main() {
    Simple A;
    Simple B;

    std::string Foo = A.Test(std::string("Foo"));
    std::string Bar = B.Test(std::string("Bar"));

    std::cout << Foo << ' ' << Bar << std::endl;
}
```

The behavior I expected would have resulted in the output of

> Foo Bar

Is there a simple alternative that would result in the behavior I expected?

**Edit**

A cutdown version of the class that has the issue:

```
class SignalManager {
    private:
        template<typename T> struct FunctionPointer { typedef boost::function1<void, const T &> type; };
        template<typename T> struct Array { typedef std::vector<typename FunctionPointer<T>::type> type; };

        template<typename T>
        typename Array<T>::type & GetArray() {
            static typename Array<T>::type Array;
            return Array;
        }

    public:
        template<typename T, typename M>
        void Broadcast(const M & Value) {
            typename Array<T>::type::iterator Iterator;
            for(Iterator = GetArray<T>().begin(); Iterator != GetArray<T>().end(); ++Iterator) {
                (*Iterator)(Value);
            }
        }

        template<typename T, typename F>
        void Connect(const F & Function) {
            GetArray<T>().push_back(Function);
        }
};
```

Comment: it isn't at all clear what it is you are trying to accomplish. If you remove `static` or perform an assigned right after your static variable declaration (as suggested by Mahesh), they'll both give you the expected output.

Comment: @Victor In the code sample I am misusing static to generate anonymous member variables at compile time. Subsequent calls to `GetArray` would return a refrence to the anonymous member variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your confusion, the alternative is member variables...

```
template<typename T>
struct Simple {
    T storage;

    T & Test(const T & Value) {
        storage = Value;
        return Storage;
    }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using the static variable to store data for the class, so I can look up type `int` and retrieve whatever I have stored there.

Comment: That's more of a design limitation of your system. For that, you need to put data into a type-less field and store some sort of identifier with it and use that to get your data back. End humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
static T Storage = Value;
```

The above statement gets executed only once despite multiple calls to member function `Test`. So, instead separate the declaration and initialization.

```
template<typename T>
T & Test(const T & Value) {         
     static T Storage;
     Storage = Value;   // Now, this is guaranteed to execute during member function calls.
    return Storage;
}
```

This should get what you want.

Comment: But storage is still static so the next class instance to execute it still overrides the value, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If each instance requires it's own variable, then there is no point for OP to declare it as static at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make it into a regular, non-static class variable, although this would require the class to be a template instead of the function...

```
template<typename T>
struct Simple
{
    T& Test( const T& value )
    {
        storage = value;
        return storage;
    }
private:
    T storage;
}
```